# Converting odds to probability

Tags: probability

I cannot understand [this table](http://www.oddschecker.com/football/world-cup/winner) . By taking one colum we have the odds of winning the World Cup of each team.

How do you convert these odds to probability, such that the sum of probabilities is 1? (=1 because one team will win the Cup)

If I simply calculate the probability as $P(t) = {1 \over odds(t)} $ doesn't work as $\sum_{t \in T} P(t) \neq 1$

Answer (score 2):

This is simple when a bookmaker offers you odds of say 6:4 the bookmaker is saying that if you win I'll give you six pounds but if you lose you have to give me four pounds.

In practise the bookmaker will usually take your stake (4 pounds) up front to make sure you actually pay him if you lose and will return it to you together with your winnings (6 pounds) if you win.

The probability is

$$\frac{\text{stake}}{\text{stake}+\text{winnings}}$$

in this case

$$\frac{4}{4+6} = \frac{4}{10} = 0.4$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to compute like this: $P(t) = \frac{odds(t)}{\sum _{t\in T}odds(t)}$, if the odds are for winning.
However, if its bet amount, then it would be inversely proportional to odds of winning, and I'm not sure how to calculate in this case, however something like $\frac{1}{odds}$ might work. Though a better thing would be to compute the new $p(t)$ as $p(t) = \frac{1}{(n-1)}(1-P(t))$

Comment: The first formula isn't correct. In fact, in this example, the probability of winning of Brazil results far lower than that of Honduras.

Comment: The first is used when when we know what the team is going to win, on average. As I mentioned if this is high then the return on bet amount for that team would be very low, as the win is very likely to happen. Conversely, when a team's average score is low the return for someone on that team will be high, as the risk is higher. I am not sure if I'm able to convey my thoughts, let me find some site with a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a solution:

$P(t) = {{1 \over odd(t)}\over \sum_{t \in T}odd(t)}$

I think that normalization is needed only because the declared odds includes some "entropy" due to the need of earning of the bank.

Comment: Looks like you found a soln. similar to the one I mentioned :D. The denominator must also be $\frac{1}{odds(t)}$. But it fails when $odds(t) = 0$. so I prefer the other third form of the soln. that I mentioned.

Comment: odds(t) cannot be zero

Comment: Not in the problem you presented, but it could be in a general case. Or even if you take a team that doesn't contest. I was looking at it as a purely statistical problem, so had to cover all bases.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the odds for Brazil is 11/4. This means that when you bet 4 dollars you win 11 dollars, at the end you get 4+11 = 15 dollars